# Carousel Bootstrap - how to narrow the width of the img-wrapper?

Tags: html, css, angular, carousel

I created a slideshow with the help of Carousel Bootstrap.

But I was unable to narrow the width of the img-wrapper.

This is what i have now:
[picture of my slideshow now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaHKd.png)

How can I narrow the purple part? So it will stick to the picture? Thank you!!

`slideshow.component.html`:

```
<ngb-carousel #carousel="ngbCarousel" class="text-lg-center" #myCarousel="ngbCarousel" showNavigationArrows="true"
  interval="3000" pauseOnHover="false">
  <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let image of images;let i = index" id="{{i}}">
    <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
      <img [src]="image" alt="Random first slide" style=" max-height:300px; margin:0 auto;">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>{{titles[i]}}</h3>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

`slideshow.component.css`:

```
div{
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}

.picsum-img-wrapper{
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your carousel in Bootstrap columns, and then you can adjust it (by changing col-md-XX):

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      INSERT YOUR CAROUSEL HERE
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can also suggest using the Bootstrap carousel:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/carousel/

Comment: Thank you @Rbbn !!!! And you know how change the color of the arrows?

Comment: Hi @Mana, if you show me a url I can point it out. What I would then do is use Chrome. Then right click and choose inspect. There you can easily see which .class is being used in the CSS. You can change it right in the browser to see the results. Then go in and add it to your own CSS which will then overwrite the original CSS, on this class. I can show you in a screenshot if you provide a url. Thanks.